# Showing that if the KL divergence between two multivariate Normal distributions is zero then their covariances and means are equal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, information-theory, coding-theory

We have two, k-dimensional multivariate normal distributions $\mathcal{N}_0(\mu_0,\Sigma_0)$ and $\mathcal{N}_1(\mu_1,\Sigma_1)$ with means $\mu_0$ and $\mu_1$ and covariances $\Sigma_0$ and $\Sigma_1$. The KL divergence between the two distributions $KL(\mathcal{N}_0||\mathcal{N}_1)$ is (from wiki ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#Multivariate_normal_distributions)), also [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60680/kl-divergence-between-two-multivariate-gaussians?noredirect=1&lq=1)):

$KL(\mathcal{N}_0||\mathcal{N}_1)=\frac{1}{2}\left(tr(\Sigma_1^{-1}\Sigma_0)+(\mu_1 - \mu_0)^T\Sigma_1^{-1}(\mu_1 - \mu_0)-k+ln(\frac{det\Sigma_1}{det\Sigma_0})\right)$

It is well known that the KL divergence is positive in general and that $KL(p||q)=0$ implies $p=q$ (e.g. Gibbs inequality [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs%27_inequality)).

Now, obviously $\mathcal{N}_0=\mathcal{N}_1$ means that $\mu_1 = \mu_0$ and $\Sigma_1 = \Sigma_0$, and it is easy to confirm that the KL expression above is indeed zero in this case.

However, can we go the other way around and use **only** the KL expression above to get that $\mu_1 = \mu_0$ and $\Sigma_1 = \Sigma_0$?

I.e. how do we show that 
$KL(\mathcal{N}_0||\mathcal{N}_1)=\frac{1}{2}\left(tr(\Sigma_1^{-1}\Sigma_0)+(\mu_1 - \mu_0)^T\Sigma_1^{-1}(\mu_1 - \mu_0)-k+ln(\frac{det\Sigma_1}{det\Sigma_0})\right) = 0 \\ \implies \mu_1 = \mu_0, \Sigma_1 = \Sigma_0$

and that this is the **only** solution?

Answer (score 1):

It's a [classic proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs%27_inequality) (usually done via log-sum inequality, or Jensen - see [eg](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~anuprao/pubs/CSE533Autumn2010/lecture3.pdf)) that, in general, $KL(p ||q) \ge 0$ and (as a corolary) that $KL(p ||q) = 0 \iff p=q$  (most precisely, almost everywhere).

In your case, the latter is equivalent to having the same mean and covariance matrix.

---

Ok, I'll bite. Let's prove that 
$$tr(\Sigma_1^{-1}\Sigma_0)+\ln(\frac{\det\Sigma_1}{\det\Sigma_0})\ge k \tag{1}$$

with equality only for $\Sigma_1 = \Sigma_0$.

Letting $C=\Sigma_1^{-1}\Sigma_0$ , and noting that $\Sigma_0$ and $\Sigma_1$  (and hence also $C$) are symmetric and positive definite, we can write the LHS as

$$ tr(C) + \ln(\det C^{-1}) = tr(C) - \ln (\det C)=\sum_i \lambda_i - \ln \prod \lambda_i= \sum_i (\lambda_i - \ln \lambda_i) \tag{2}$$

where $\lambda_i \in (0,+\infty)$ are the eigenvalues of $C$.

But $x - \ln x \ge 1$, for all $x>0$ with equality only when $x=1$.

Then
$$ tr(C) + \ln(\det C^{-1}) \ge k \tag{3}$$

with equality only if all eigenvalues are $1$, i.e. if $C=I$, i.e. if $\Sigma_1 = \Sigma_0$.

Hence $(1)$ is proved.

To complete the proof:   $w^T \Sigma_1^{-1} w \ge 0$, with equality only when $w = 0$ (positive definite quadratic form). Hence the desired property follows: $KL(\mathcal{N}_0||\mathcal{N}_1) =0 \iff \Sigma_1 = \Sigma_0, \mu_1 = \mu_0$

Notice that all this requires that the covariances matrices are strictly positive definite, i.e. that the densities are not degenerate.

Comment: Could you please expand on "In your case, the latter is equivalent to having the same mean and covariance matrix" - staring at the expression for the KL between Gaussians it is not obvious to me that having the same mean and covariance matrix is the **only** solution for having KL = 0. That is the part I am interested in. I edited the question to further clarify that.

Comment: You shouldn't stare at the expression for the KL. You should only understand and accept the implication above, then merely stare at the densities, and ask yourself when they are equal; answer: when (and only when) they have the same mean and covariance.

Comment: The statement $KL(p ||q) = 0 \iff p=q$ is not easy to see, nor in the general case, nor in these particular case (two gaussians).

Comment: I appreciate the advice but what I am interested in is whether the matrix equation the KL entails can be shown to have a unique solution. There are 4 (multivariate) unknowns in that equations so 1) it either has certain properties that can be used to show that the solution is unique, in which case I'd like to know those properties 2) it can't be done, in which case I'll move on.